# Emails from a VPS server usually go to spam folder?

Tags: web-hosting, email, spam, vps

I found that the emails sent from my VPS server usually go to the spam folder in popular email providers such as hotmail or gmail.

Is it because the VPS IP has been marked as a spam server? (Other account using this VPS IP have/had been sending spam emails)

Any solution for this kind of situation?

Comment: Look up your server on [senderbase](http://www.senderbase.org/) -- this will tell you if your server has a bad reputation for emails, and if it appears on any blacklists.

Comment: The reputation in senderbase shows "Neutral".

Comment: Then the problem is typically going to be either with the configuration of your server, or the content of your messages. Just being on a VPS shouldn't have an impact (unless a *lot* of your neighbors are bad apples).

Comment: Is it possible to provide an answer about the configuration of the server or the content of the message you refer to?

Comment: With the amount of detail included in your question, frankly, no. And I'm not certain running of mail servers is on-topic here.

Comment: Some of the information you need to provide for a more thorough response: • example of the emails you are sending; • volume that you're sending; • what MTA you are using; • whether you've done (at a minimum) the steps listed [here](http://www.linuxmail.info/mail-server-checklist/).

Comment: Sorry but this question appears to be considered duplicate due to the fact there is already dozens of questions and answers in various forms regarding [stop email being marked as spam](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=mail+spam).

Comment: I am just trying to know if there is any specific case when using VPS...  for example, it's easy to be marked as spam because VPS hosts have many spamming neighbors, etc